# trying to receive data from remote device using udp socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to send a command to a remote device: [E5071C ENA Vector Network Analyzer](https://www.keysight.com/en/pdx-x202270-pn-E5071C/ena-vector-network-analyzer?cc=US&lc=eng)

**These are my problems:**

- When I try to send and receive data from the socket, it "hangs".
- I am not sure which type of socket I should use.

For the other commands, I used `s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)`, but I only had to send data in those cases. Here I need to send *and* receive data. I have tried to use a `while True`loop like this:

```py
while True:
    s.settimeout(1)
    print(sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection')
    connection, client_address = s.accept()
    try:
        print(sys.stderr, 'client connected:', client_address)
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(1024)
            print(sys.stderr, 'received "%s"') % data
            if data:
                connection.sendall(data)
            else:
                break
    finally:
        connection.close()
```

I could not get the result I wanted with the while loop either, so this is what I have so far instead:

```py
## import modules
## for loop iterations
## commands sent to remote device using UDP socket

def is_hanging(host, port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((host,port))
    min_msg = ':CALCulate:SELected:MARKer:FUNCtion:TYPE MINimum'
    s.send(min_msg.encode())
    s.settimeout(1)
    try:
        s.recv(1024)
        print("Received data!")
        return True
    except socket.timeout as e:
        print(e)
        return False
    finally:
        s.close()

if is_hanging('10.5.33.16',5025) is True:
    pass
else:
    raise Exception("Could not receive data.")
```

I am not entirely sure how `s.recv` works, but I what I am hoping/expecting is that data I send to the remote device generates a response which sent back to me.
Right now it is just hanging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.accept()` is only relevant in the context of a stream-based socket that's been configured as a listening socket. It doesn't make sense to use on a datagram socket, especially one that's already associated with a remote host.

(Are you sure `SOCK_DGRAM` -- i.e. UDP -- is correct here? Most SCPI devices I've worked with use TCP, i.e. `SOCK_STREAM`.)

If you're sure that you're using the right protocol, remove the call to `s.accept()`, and call `.recv()` on the existing socket `s`.

Comment: I sent the other two commands to a datagram socket, should send this one the same way? My problem is trying to receive data. Should I use a TCP or UDP socket for this?

Comment: Are you sure the device is _listening_ on a UDP socket? Do you have a link to some documentation for this device?

Comment: here is the link for the device: [https://www.keysight.com/en/pdx-x202270-pn-E5071C/ena-vector-network-analyzer?cc=US&lc=eng] I am pretty sure the device is listening on a UDP socket because the other commands can interact with the device. I used `SOCK_DGRAM` for sending the other commands.

Comment: [The information in the manual](http://ena.support.keysight.com/e5071c/manuals/webhelp/eng/programming/remote_control/overview/lan_remote_control_system.htm) indicates that you should be using TCP over port 5024 or 5025. I don't see any references to port 20850 anywhere.

Comment: No, you're still trying to send a UDP datagram, which the device will ignore.